# Excel Formula To Find Cells That Have The Text "INV" with space/s after it then the numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have worksheet that has a narrative column. I have to locate cells that has the text "INV" and then space or spaces before the numeric digits (example: INV 1425190). I need to find them to highlight them as they need to be fixed by removing the space. There are different scenarios, some of them would only have one space between the text INV and the numbers but there are also other instances wherein there can be multiple spaces? Is there a way to put this in an Excel formula?
Another solution would be to create a formula that ensures there's are 7 number digits following the INV text without any spaces between the text and the numbers (example: INV1425190). Appreciate your help on this. Many thanks.

I tried using the `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("INV ",[@Narrative])),"Yes","No")` but is there a better way?

| Narrative |
| --- |
| PAID INV 1425290 FROM SYD CAPITAL |
| Transfer INV/ 125391 ref:32125 |
| 20001452563312 HSBC city |
| Payment INV1526352 Aug ST |
| Transfer INVOICE from Sep |
| Transfer INV-2252421 OCT |
| Payment INV1572463 Aug C1280 |
| PAID INV 1353423 FROM ANZ |

Comment: If the text were in A1 then you could use the formula `="INV"&TRIM(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-3))`

Comment: thank you for that but it didn't work as my cell would  have other text before and after the text "INV" (example: PAID INV 1425190 FROM SYD CAPITAL). There are also instances where the text "INV" is either followed by other symbols like / and - before the numerical digits.

Comment: try googling the use of 'SUBSTITUE' formula to replace space " " with nothing "".

Comment: @kimini can you post few samples of your data, using **[Markdown_Table_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)** just wanted see why you're not able to parse the spaces, also show your expected output.

Comment: | Narrative                         |
| --------------------------------- |
| PAID INV 1425290 FROM SYD CAPITAL |
| Transfer INV/ 125391 ref:32125    |
| 20001452563312 HSBC city          |
| Payment INV1526352  Aug ST        |
| Transfer INVOICE from Sep         |
| Transfer INV-2252421 OCT          |
| Payment INV1572463  Aug C1280     |
| PAID INV    1353423 FROM ANZ      |

Comment: As this is just part of some checks that I need to do on the file before using VBA to update the records with incorrect format and creating the final upload file in another sheet, i just need to be able to identify all the cells with incorrect format and highlight them so that the user can fix them or are there any other suggestions to automate this part also using a formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I have understood from the given samples, then the following formula should work :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=IF(OR(COUNT(SEARCH({"INV","INVOICE"},A2))={0,2}),A2,
 MID(A2,1,SEARCH("INV",A2)+2)&TRIM(REPLACE(A2,1,SEARCH("INV",A2)+3,"")))
```

---

To explain how the above formula is executing the algorithm:

- Firstly we are checking whether there is a `INV` or `INVOICE` within the string or not

[image]

---

```
=SEARCH({"INV","INVOICE"},A2)
```

---

- Next, we are wrapping it within <kbd>COUNT()</kbd> function to get the counts, since those which don't have `INV` or `INVOICE` shall return an error and also where it has both it gives us a count of 2

[image]

---

```
=COUNT(SEARCH({"INV","INVOICE"},A2))
```

---

- We need to work with those which shows as `1` hence applying an <kbd>OR()</kbd> function to exclude the `1`s and return those without the `INV` as `TRUE` value arguments.

[image]

---

```
=OR(COUNT(SEARCH({"INV","INVOICE"},A2))={0,2})
```

---

- When wrapped within an <kbd>IF()</kbd> function (excuse the ones which shows `0` -- i will come to the following bullets)

[image]

---

```
=IF(OR(COUNT(SEARCH({"INV","INVOICE"},A2))={0,2}),A2,)
```

---

- Now, the final part of the formula:

[image]

---

```
=MID(A2,1,SEARCH("INV",A2)+2)&TRIM(REPLACE(A2,1,SEARCH("INV",A2)+3,""))
```

---

It has broken down into two the first part takes the data before the word `INV` including it which is

```
=MID(A2,1,SEARCH("INV",A2)+2)
```

---

And the second part takes the data after the `INV` bt excludes the unwanted or the offending ones.

```
=TRIM(REPLACE(A2,1,SEARCH("INV",A2)+3,""))
```

---

Joining them both using an `Ampersand` --> `&` combines them into one to get the desired result.

---

Since not aware of the excel version, may be it can be simplified more with the modern version of functions available in excel. If I am able to succeed shall update the same. However, the present formula shall work with any versions of excel.

---

### EDIT:

Found the last formula had a flaw, so here is an updated one:

[image]

---

```
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"INV ","INV-","INV/ "},A2)),
  MID(A2,1,SEARCH("INV",A2)+2)&TRIM(REPLACE(A2,1,SEARCH("INV",A2)+3,"")),A2)
```

---

A more compact solution, i think using the functions available in `MS365`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=LET(α, A2:A9, φ, {"INV-","INV ","INV/ "}, 
 IFERROR(TEXTBEFORE(α,φ)&"INV",α)&TEXTAFTER(α,φ,,,,""))
```

---

A better option I think, using the <kbd>TEXTSPLIT( )</kbd> &  <kbd>TEXTJOIN( )</kbd> function.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN("INV",1,TEXTSPLIT(A2,{"INV-","INV ","INV/ "}))
```

---

Comment: it works! thank you Mayukh! if it's not too much, are you please able to provide me a brief explanation of the formula so that I can understand it better?

Comment: @kimini yes sure thing, yes i am updating the post with the explanations